# rsync exclude hidden files doesnt work!

Tags: rsync, hidden-files

I’ve searched all over the internet and everybody suggests the same thing - that adding `--exclude=´.*´` should exclude hidden files and folders from an rsync.  It doesn’t.  I´ve also tried adding a slash and/or double quotes eg. `--exclude=¨\.*¨` Nothing seems to work. AGH!! Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Both versions you are showing are wrong. You need to use double quotes. The following works and excludes hidden files and directories:

```
--exclude=".*"
```

If you only want to exclude hidden directories:

```
--exclude=".*/"
```

Comment: single quotes are fine, and you can also escape the globbing

Answer (score 8):

I use this expression: `--exclude=".[!.]*"`

Does the job well for me excluding hidden files and directories.

Answer (score 3):

Open a text file `exclude_me.txt` and type the following: `.[a-z]*`

Then execute the following:

```
rsync -avh --exclude-from='exclude_me.txt' /path/of/Source /path/of/Destination
```

Comment: This article explains it in detail (may be useful): https://www.howtogeek.com/168009/how-to-exclude-files-from-rsync/

Answer (score 1):

`--exclude="/.*"` your `\` is pointing the wrong way .

```
rsync -a --exclude="/.*" ./ /path/to/sync
```

Comment: There is no need for the / :) he is not using "'s. If he needed a / is should be at the end to exclude dirs.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `rsync` command I use to make a copy of my local Dropbox folder, from my MacBook (MacOS) to an external network drive (mounted as extdisk below).

`rsync -atv --delete --delete-excluded --exclude "DontCopyThisFolder" --exclude=".*" "/Users/admin/Dropbox/" "/Volumes/extdisk/Files/Dropbox/"`

It uses the options:

- **a**rchive
- perserve **t**imes (on files & folders)
- **v**erbose progress output (to see what is going on)
- **delete** and **delete-excluded** will remove all files *from the destination* that are not included in the list of files to copy. This also removes files that might have been copied by other means, but now isn't, because of the **exclude "DontCopyThisFolder"**-option, or the **exclude=".*"**-option that will exclude files starting with a dot.

Further documentation and options can be found at the [rsync Man Page](https://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html)

Comment: The version of `rsync` that comes with Mac OS has a strange quirk: If you use the `-E` option it doesn't allow you to exclude dotfiles. So `exclude=".*"` or `exclude="._*"` have no effect in combination with `-E` .