# How to property setup rsync?

Tags: backup, rsync

I want to sync all files and folders in my home directory expect for the ones that start with .

This is what I have done so far:

```
rsync -azPnv --delete /home/USER/ DESTINATION
```

In order to ignore *hidden files*, I guess that I have to utilize `--exclude` and `--include` as well but I am not sure how. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [rsync exclude hidden files doesnt work!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/482916/rsync-exclude-hidden-files-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `--exclude` parameter to ignore files and folders. For hidden files and folders (filename or folder name starts with a `.`) use the parameter below:

```
--exclude "**/.*"
```

This means, match all files and folders which starts with a `.` in all folders recursively.

- The glob `**` will recursively match all files and directories
- `*` will match any number of characters

<sub>[More infos about pathname expansion (globbing)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs)</sub>

From `man rsync`

```
--exclude=PATTERN
      exclude files matching PATTERN
```